How to set a field in a Kustomize project dynamically?
We have an app described by a Kustomize project, deployed on Openshift by ArgoCD. The Namespace where the app is deployed is defined by ArgoCD (unknown in the Kustomize base & overlays).
Whithin the app, we have to define this Dapr Configuration:
---
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: invocation-allowlist
spec:
  accessControl:
    defaultAction: deny
    trustDomain: public
    policies:
      - appId: app-backend
        defaultAction: allow
        namespace: currentNamespace
        trustDomain: public

How can we have the namespace field dynamically set to the Namespace where the app is deployed (without changing the stack involved)?

I don't think there's a way to do this with argocd. You could potentially create a mutatingwebhook in your target namespace that would update the Configuration resource when it gets submitted by argocd.
